# How can I create a plugin to insert templated html within a text plugin in Django CMS

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm fairly new to Django CMS so please forgive me if my terminology isn't right.

I have a page with a placeholder within which I have added some html using the Text plugin. Within that, I would like to be able to add one or many pre-templated pieces of html.

I have looked into building my own plugin but the documentation that I've been reading [here](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/custom_plugins.html#the-simplest-plugin) only allows the plugin to be added from outside the actual text plugin page and renders the result beneath my text plugin content. I've found the section on [Nested Plugins](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/custom_plugins.html#nested-plugins), but I'm trying to nest my plugin within the built-in Text plugin which that doesn't seem to cover.

What I'm looking for is to be able to build something so that it places block-level html elements within the content like the Link or Image plugins (in my case, it would be some block-level html content).

How can I do this, or where can I find some more information on how this can be done?

Comment: Plugins can be added inside a text plugin, theres a special menu button for it in the GUI. You can write your own plugins or maybe just switch to the HTML view of the text plugin & drop your markup directly in there? http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/plugins.html#cms.plugin_base.CMSPluginBase.text_enabled

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was following the same route as nageeb. The problem with your solution seems to be that djangocms TEXT plugin DOESN't allow arbitrary HTML code blocks. The right plugin to use in this situation is SNIPPET. More details here: https://github.com/divio/djangocms-snippet